# How to read directive model value in its main controller using angular2

Tags: angular

I have person page with directive

```
    <person-directive *ngFor="let person of persons; #idx = index" (remove) = "removePerson(idx)">
    </person-directive>
```

And person directive has some input fields listed below. I want to access the those input value in person page controller.

```
 <div class="group">
           <label class="person-involved-name">Name</label>
           <div class="textContainer"><input type="text" value="" name="nameSelect_1" id="nameSelect_1" [(ngModel)]="personData.nameSelect_1" class="txt-box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
           <label class="person-involved-aliasname">Alias Name</label>
           <div class="textContainer"><input type="text" value="" name="aliasNameSelect_1" id="aliasNameSelect_1" [(ngModel)]="personData.aliasNameSelect_1" class="txt-box"></div>
           <div><br class="clr"></div>
        </div>
```

personDirective.ts is defined below.

```
export class PersonDirective {
 public personData;
```

}

and person.ts is defined below.

```
 export class PersonInvolvedComponent { 
     persons: Array<PersonDirective> = [];
     constructor( private router: Router, 
                 private _globalService:GlobalService) {
         this.persons.push(new PersonDirective());
 }

}
```

I can able to access the those input value in directive.ts file but not in PersonInvolvedComponent.ts file. I can only see the "personData" object but not the real input values added to it. How can I access it. Please suggest me.

Comment: can you please post your full code for `personDirective.ts` and  `person.ts`?

Answer (score 1):

I think in angular -2 it is not possible to render the html with the help of directive,so you can use the component for rendering and doing some stuffs.

To achive the above said scenario , please follow the steps

1. create the component using @component decorator and give the value of selector as person 
   `@component({
       moduleId: module.id,
       selector : 'person',
       templateUrl : './person.html'
   })
   export class PersonInvolvedComponent {
      // do the needed stuffs
   }`
2. copy the HTML code that are needed for person detaila and paste in person .html file.
3. now use the selector(person) according to your need.

   ```
   <div *for="let person of personDetails">
      <person [neededInput]="person" (output)="neederStuffs()" > </person>
   </div>
   ```

Try this and revert me if you have any queries

Comment: Directive means, its a component only.. many person component made a personDetails in my case. And I want to access the each person input value in personDetail component. Whatever the values I am accessing in personComponent need to access in personDetails component too. I can able to access the object personDetails but not the input value added to it. What exactly [neededInput]="person" , (output)="neederStuffs()" will do..

Comment: [] - denotes the input value from parent component to child component ()

Comment: I treid like [personData] ="", but if I access the personData in component I get empty object.. I can access using this.person.personData. But it doesnt show any input field or value I have typed

Comment: example - `<div *for="let person of personDetails">
   <person [detail]="person" (deletePerson)="delete()" > </person>
</div>` the above code is parent component.

Comment: Now child component. `@component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector : 'person',
    templateUrl : './person.html'
})
export class PersonInvolvedComponent {
   @input()  Details : details;  @output() deleteUser; deletePerson() {  this.deleteUser.emit(); } 
}`

Comment: I my case personInvolved is parent n it has multiple child class person. so I have added input property in person class. I can able to access in personDetails also. But whatever the value we are giving in input field its not showing up. for example I have added [(ngModel)]="personData.nameSelect_1" so if I access the personData in personDetails its should have personData = {nameSelect_1:""} right ? I can see this result in person class but in personDetails class I can see only personData = {}

Comment: I think you are not maintaining the model correctly.create one array of person.when input is saved please push the person to that perticular array then you can have all datas

Comment: I have this array..     addPerson() {
  this.persons.push(new PersonDirective());
 }

Answer (score 0):

Check it after applying below changes :

//person page change

```
<person-directive *ngFor="let person of persons; #idx = index" (remove)="removePerson(idx)" [data]="person" ></person-directive>
```

// personDirective.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector   : 'person-directive',
  templateUrl: './person-directive.html'
})
export class PersonDirective {
  @Input() public data: any;      
}
```

//person-directive.html

```
<div class="group">
  <label class="person-involved-name">Name</label>
  <div class="textContainer"><input type="text" value="" name="nameSelect_1" id="nameSelect_1" [(ngModel)]="data.nameSelect_1" class="txt-box"></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <label class="person-involved-aliasname">Alias Name</label>
  <div class="textContainer"><input type="text" value="" name="aliasNameSelect_1" id="aliasNameSelect_1" [(ngModel)]="data.aliasNameSelect_1" class="txt-box"></div>
  <div><br class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did not work.. I want child classes values. This name and alias will be changed after adding the one more child. Need to maintain the array. How can I achieve it