# Emit event from parent to child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Submit`button in the parent component namely`personDetails`.`personDetails`has many`person` components. Whenever I click on the Submit button, I want to call a method in child component.

How can I emit an event from a parent to a child component using `@Output`?

Its easy to do it from the child to the parent. I want to access a value of the child component, hence I need to emit an event from parent to child.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can create one service which is shared between your parent and child component in which you can define `Observable` so that you can subscribe to that `Observable` from child and perform some action when you receive some value from parent.

```
//common.service.ts

import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  private notify = new Subject<any>();
  /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
  notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  public notifyOther(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.notify.next(data);
    }
  }
}
```

//parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector   : 'parent',
  templateUrl : './parent.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor( private commonService: CommonService ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.notifyOther({option: 'call_child', value: 'From child'});
  }
}
```

//child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector   : 'child',
  templateUrl : './child.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor( private commonService: CommonService ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.commonService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'call_child') {
        console.log(res.value);
        // perform your other action from here

      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: please go through this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717465/how-to-read-directive-model-value-in-its-main-controller-using-angular2/39719175?noredirect=1#comment66739597_39719175.. Here I have mentioned parent and child component. Please tell me how can I access that personDetails object in parent. Or how can I call the submit method in child.. This question is similar this link

Comment: How to attach a event from parent html to child.. For example there is a submit button in parent, when I click it how can fire it in child. Instead of ngOnInit() can I use submit() ?

Comment: when you click on submit from `parent` then call `notifyOther` of `commonService` with some params and check that params value in `child` by subscribing it and based on params value call you action of child.

Comment: I am getting No provider for CommonService! error.. Should I add any providers

Comment: You have to add `CommonService` in your module or component's provider metadata declaration

Comment: @ranakrunal9, I did exactly the same but unfortunately my code is not working. Another thing is you've defined `notifyObservable$` as a observable but in child component you subscribe with `submitObservable$`.

Comment: @ranakrunal9, no error but the problem i'm facing is, my service is passing the data to parent component with `next`, but in the parent ngOnInit, the subscribe portion is not being hit. Any guesses?

Comment: if you have added condition on `res` inside `subscribe` then remove it and check it once and make sure you share same instance of `CommonService` in your parent and child component

Comment: The answer provided by @ranakrunal9 is correct. Subjects can act like EventListeners . And that in a way can be used for sending an event listener in child, a value from the parent. And the preferred way of achieving this is by using Subject and not a plain Observable

Answer (score 21):

### Child Component

In `childComponent.ts`

```
@Input() private uploadSuccess: EventEmitter<boolean>;
```

Additionally in `childComponent.ts` subscribe to the event:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.uploadSuccess) {
    this.uploadSuccess.subscribe(data => {
      // Do something in the childComponent after parent emits the event.
    });
  }
}
```

### Parent Component

In `ParentComponent.html`

```
<app-gallery  [uploadSuccess] = "uploadSuccess" > </app-gallery>
```

In `ParentComponent.ts`

```
private uploadSuccess: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

onImageUploadSuccess(event) {
   console.log('Image Upload succes');
   if (event.code === 'OK' && this.maxUploadLimit > 0) {
      this.galleryImagesCount = this.galleryImagesCount + 1;
      this.maxUploadLimit = this.maxUploadLimit - 1;
    }

   // The parent emits the event which was given as `@Input` variable to the child-component
   this.uploadSuccess.emit(true);
}
```

Comment: perfect comment. Only little change to succed fully check from typescript add "!": @Input() private uploadSuccess!: EventEmitter<boolean>;