# Implementing observable fails because ionic 2 forgets Observer

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

Am trying to implement observable with the following class

```
import {Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';

@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {

dataChange: Observable<any>;
dataChangeObserver: Observer<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.dataChange = new Observable((observer) => {
            this.dataChangeObserver = observer;
        }).share();
    }

    setDate(date: any) {
        this.dataChangeObserver.next(date);
    }
}
```

When calling `setDate()` with a value am getting the following error

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
```

It seems that the Observer `dataChangeObserver` is not defined. But when debugging i can see that `dataChangeObserver` value i set. But Ionic 2 somehow forgets about it when calling `setDate(date: any)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer of Question [can i emmit the event from parent to child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2/39739184#39739184) to see how to set `Observable` and how to subscribe to it.