# Create custom Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

it is possible (and correct) to create a custom observable ?
For example, if i have data in my cache, i would like create custom observable before make a http request:

my request:

```
private device: Device;
getDeviceById(deviceId): Observable<Device> {
    if(this.device._id == deviceId) {
        let myObservable = new Observable('with my device'); 
        return myObservable;
    } else return this.http.get('/api/device/get/'+deviceId)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Thank's

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Why you couldn't create a custom Observable? Or you want to use an observable instead of the `http` request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create one subject to work as observable as explained on answer [can i emmit the event from parent to child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2/39739184#39739184) and use it when you have data in your cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
getDeviceById(deviceId): Observable<Device> {
if(this.authProvider == deviceId) {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next("something");
        observer.complete();
    });
} else return this.http.get('/api/device/get/'+deviceId)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: i already try with this but the returned Observable is not the type "Observable<Device>"

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');

var subscription = Rx.Observable.create(function(obs) {
  button.onclick = function(event) {
  obs.next(event);
}
.subscribe(function(value) {
   console.log(value);
},);
```

see more in that link: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methods to create Observables in RxJS. Subjects and Operators.

See Below Example:

```
const obs$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  //Will Thorow error
 //observer.error(new Error("Limit Exceed"));
  observer.next(3);
  //To stop execution after 
  observer.complete();
});

//Handle Subscription
custObs1.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this._desingUtility.print(res, "elContainer");
      },
      (error) => {
        this.status = "error";
      },
      () => {
        this.status = "completed";
      }
    );

//OutPut : 
1
2
3
```

https://www.tutscoder.com/post/custom-observable

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31180126)