# Angular2 Communication between two components with EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components: `AppComp` and `SimulationComp`

`AppComp` contains one function :

```
generateEmptyPromise() {
   return Promise.resolved('')
}
```

and has the following html :

```
<simulation-comp (simu)='generateEmptyPromise()'></simulation-comp>
```

Simulation comp handles the `(simu)` like this :

```
@Output() simu = new EventEmitter()
private eventHandled: boolean = false

// Triggered when a button of the component is pressed
whenClicked() {
  this.simu.subscribe(() => {
     this.eventHandled= true
  })
  this.simu.emit()
}
```

What I would like is `eventHandled` to become true based on the promise given by `generateEmptyPromise` (so after that the emit has been handled). However, it's not working atm, how could I adapt my code to have this behavior ? Maybe it is not supposed to work like this, and I am getting it completly wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I emmit the event from parent to child in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

`@Output` is for sending values 'outside' of the component back to the parent. Child -> Parent.

For Parent -> Child Communication where the parent template consist of the child it wants to communicate with you need `@Input` so the child knows the parent will send those values at some point in time.

So for starting you might want `appCmp`

`<simulation-comp [myinput]='generateEmptyPromise()'></simulation-comp>`

Inside

`SimulationCmp.ts`

`@Input myinput : any //Whatever value type you expect it to be`