# Pass Callback function via @Input in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components `Main` (parent) and `Header` (child). I want to add buttons in my `Header` component from the `Main` component. Clicking the button should change a state in my `Main` component. I don't want it to be hardcoded, but rather passing an Array of objects from `Main` component to `Header` component. Clicking the button in header should trigger a state change in my `Main` component. I know how to do it by using `@Input` and `@Output` decorators using `EventEmitters`, however i want to provide like a callback function in the array object to call in my parent component. Is it possible to do?

Sorry if this sounds little weird - i dont know how else to explain it :)
Here is a prototype of the Array i want to pass:

`headerButtons: Array<any> = [{title: 'Button 1', callback: 'callbackMethod1'}, {title: 'Button 2', callback: 'callbackMethod2'}];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 pass callback function to child component as @Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328652/angular2-pass-callback-function-to-child-component-as-input)

Comment: if you do not want to hardcode then possibly you can use Observable as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2/39739184#39739184