# how to pass content one Component to another Component using master Component in angular 2

Tags: angular

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,MyDatePickerModule ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent,HeaderComponent,
              ContentComponent,ActionComponent ,
              FacultyComponent,StudentComponent,
              filterPipe
            ],                
  providers:    [ DataService ], 
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
 })
  export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `./app/app.components.html`,
})
export class AppComponent  { }
```

app.components.html

```
     <my-header></my-header>
     <my-content></my-content>
```

header.components.ts

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-header',
  templateUrl: `./app/header/header.components.html`
 })
 export class HeaderComponent  {
   batchObj: Task;
   myDatePickerOptions: any;  
   constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }   
}
```

header.components.html

```
      Batch : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_batch"  > <option >Select Batch</option>
                   <option *ngFor="let item of  batchObj | filterPipe: [];   ">{{item.batch}}</option>
            </select>
    Term : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_term"> <option>Select Term</option>
     <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj | filterPipe: ['batch', sel_batch,'term'];   ">{{item.term}}</option>
     </select>           
    Section : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_section"> <option>Select Section</option> 
     <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj | filterPipe: ['batch', sel_batch,'term',sel_term,'section'];">{{item.section}}</option>
    </select>
```

content.components.ts

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-content',
 templateUrl: `./app/content/content.components.html`    
 })
  export class ContentComponent  { 
 }
```

this
 `my-header` `my-content` both custom tag present in my master `app.component.ts` file

so I want to pass `three select box` value from `my-header`  to `my-content` page

1) `how to do it?`

2) I used three select box each one select box value comes when calling previous for that i used ng-model for passing value but i saw some example where passing value from one component to another use like `#sel_batch` instead of  `[(ngModel)]="sel_batch"` but then `filterPipe: ['batch', sel_batch,'term']` not work 
which syntax correct for my condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create one common service which shared between your `HeaderComponent` and `ContentComponent` and with this service you can communicate between `HeaderComponent` and `ContentComponent`. Check [Component communication via a service documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) and my answer for [parent-child or sibling component comunication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2/39739184#39739184).

After you have made common service you have to emit the events from `HeaderComponent` on select dropdown value change which needs to be already `subscribe` by `ContentComponent` so that you can perform your functionality based on dropdown value change

Comment: {option: 'call_child', value: 'From child'} what this part does? how to pass my select batch here

Comment: In `notifyOther` you are passing `{option: 'call_child', value: 'From child'}` which you will receive as `res` inside `subscribe` inside `ContentComponent`. So you can pass your value which you want to send to `ContentComponent` from `notifyOther`.

Comment: pls example consider this  **[(ngModel)]="sel_batch"** select box  how to pass in above

Comment: Try to check by passing `{option: 'batch_changed', value: this.sel_batch}` for batch  and `{option: 'term_changed', value: this.sel_term}` for term value change and inside your `subscribe` compare value of `res.option` with `term_changed` or `batch_changed` instead of `call_child`  to perform your action.

Comment: ok i will try hope this will  work me one more question most video use directive for that but its showing deprecated. any other alternative for that