# Pass data to other component using service in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to pass data from 'first' component to 'second' component using service. But When I try to retrieve data in 'second' component, It is undefined.

This is my code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { testData } from '../model/Data';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
 public constructor(private router: Router,private mydata:testData) { 
    this.mydata={firstname:"Amit",lastname:"Kumar",Mobile:"12345"};
 }
ngOnInit() { }
}
```

As I have set 'myData' in constructor. This is code in 'second' component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { testData } from '../model/Data';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private mydata:testData) {
    console.log(this.mydata.firstname);
   }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Data.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class testData{
    public firstname: string;
    public lastname: string;
    public Mobile:string;
    public constructor() { }
}
```

and updated my app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
...
providers: [testData],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

> 'Second' component is not child component of 'first'.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: @echonax: Those example for component when there is parent child relationship.

Comment: Title is a bit misleading but your answer is in _Parent and children communicate via a service_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477285/how-to-pass-content-one-component-to-aanother-component-using-master-component-in/41477625#41477625

Comment: @echonax: I read that tutorial. But could find my mistake. As My service is singleton. so I should get same instance in 'second' controller.  Could you please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this assignment

```
this.mydata={firstname:"Amit",lastname:"Kumar",Mobile:"12345"};
```

You are not assigning the properties of your service. You are assigning you `mydata` field to become an another object.

I think what you meant to do is,

```
this.mydata.firstname = "Amit";
this.mydata.lastname = "Kumar";
this.mydata.Mobile = "12345";
```

If you want to refer to the whole object you should use a `Subject` like in the documentation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Note: This approach still might not work in some cases; like if `FirstComponent` can't set the fields fast enough and `SecondComponent` tries to get them before..